# Symfony2 - Error Handler for specific Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

In my current Project I have several Bundles. One Bundle is for a REST API in which I need to return a JsonResponse on Errors with a custom message. The other Bundles should display a HTML Error Page. Now I added an "ExceptionListener" with an "onKernelException"-Method, which unfortunately will always be triggered.

How can I set up different an Error Handling for each Bundle? Or is there some good/practical/other way to set up different Responses if an error occurred depending on the Bundle?

Comment: Your response should depend on the type of request, but not on the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

extend the JsonResponse with your own class (`RestfulJsonResponse extends JsonResponse`) and make all your responses use your new response in the bundle (`use RestfulJsonResponse as JsonResponse`)

Then in your listener, just check for the type of response:

```
if ($response instanceof RestfulJsonResponse) {
    // do your thing
}
```

Comment: But I want to know how to handle Exceptions\Errors differently depending on the bundle. The regular Response is not the problem.

Comment: I understand, but the Response probably doesn't know about the Bundle it came from. You could set the BundleName as a response Attribute and filter in a similar manner to what I have outlined above, but you need to setup some kind of filterable data.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. It's dirty, but will work until I find something better.

My ExceptionHandler detects the executed Bundle through the Controller attached to the Request. If it's the REST API Bundle it will return a JsonResponse, otherwise it will return so the Symfony Exception Handling will be executed.